# Dynamic sidebar areas not working on the Theme Customizer

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, widgets, theme-customizer, register-sidebar

I am trying to create one sidebar area per page in a WordPress site. For example, if a WordPress installation has 2 pages: 'Home' and 'Blog', then there'll be two sidebar areas, 'Home sidebar area' and 'Blog sidebar area'. I thought I could just loop through the pages and create the sidebar areas dynamically, like so:

```
// functions.php
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'xxx_widgets_init' );
function xxx_widgets_init() {

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            $the_query->the_post();

           register_sidebar( array(
             'name'          =>  'Widget name',
             'id'            => 'widget-id-' . $post->ID,
             'description'   => __( 'Widget desc', 'xxx' ),
             'before_widget' => '<div>',
             'after_widget'  => '</div>',
             'before_title'  => '',
             'after_title'   => '',
           ) );

        }

        //Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }

}
```

This works, I can see one sidebar area per page. Furthermore, if I create a third page, the third sidebar area gets instantly created without issues, as expected.

I go to appearances > widgets, and add a few widgets to my dynamic sidebar areas, and they get saved successfully.

**The issue is, there is a unexpected behavior when doing this exact same thing, but in the theme customizer:**

If I go to the Customizer > Widgets > [I can see my widget areas here OK] > ...
If I try to add a widget, **what appears to be an infinite autosave is triggered, and it's not possible to add, edit or move widgets around**. Can you tell if there's anything wrong with this approach to create dynamic widget areas ?

Comment: Wouldn't this create a sidebar area for each post on an archive page, such as Blog?

Comment: @NathanPowell it is my understanding that the following line
"$args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' );" targets only the pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating new query objects is not a good idea in this situation. Try simply getting the pages and using those objects to serve up the widget areas:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_243057_widgets_init' );

function my_243057_widgets_init() {

    /**
     * Get only published page objects
     * @link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages
     */
    $pages = get_pages();

    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {

        register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          =>  'Widget name',
            'id'            => 'widget-id-' . $page->ID,
            'description'   => __( 'Widget for page: ' . $page->post_title ),
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '',
            'after_title'   => '',
        ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: This works indeed, any idea why it is not possible to do it inside a loop ? -- Thanks for the help.

Comment: Basically "The Loop" is intended for templates and display from what I understand. I don't use it much, so I can't really explain.

Comment: Essentially the `have_posts()` method of that object screws this up.